# Can't access property of class from another class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a class named Card:

```
class Card {
    constructor() {
        this.container = document.getElementById('main');
        this.element = document.createE( 'div', {class: "card" } );
        this.container.appendChild( this.element );

        this.setImage();

    }

    setImage() {
       //I do an instance of image in here
       new Image()
    }
}
```

And I have another class bellow called Image:

```
class Image {
    constructor( image ) {
        this.element = document.createE( 'img', { class: "image" } );
        //then in here I expect to be able to access card.container to append child
        // But it's here when I got the error main.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot 
        access 'card' before initialization
        card.container.appendChild( this.element );
    }
}
```

And I initalize the class Card right at the end of the document as:

```
let card = new Card()
```

How can I use card properties from the class Image?

Comment: well how can you use something before it is made?

Comment: You could pass the `Card` instance into the `Image` constructor as a parameter.

Comment: this.image =  this.setImage();
you are not assigning the image to a property

Comment: Sounds like you're using `new Image` before the code initializing `card` at the end of the document, as the error message is saying.

Comment: (Side note: There's already a default `Image` function in the web environment, I'd probably steer clear of that name.)

Comment: Why are you using Global Variables in an OO design? Sort of defeats the purpose of being able to reuse it. Seems like the Card code should be appending it, the image code should not be....

Answer (score 0):

You are using `let`, which must be declared ***before*** it is accessed. To fix your error, move the `let card = new Card()` to the ***top*** of the document.

Quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description:

> **Note:** Many issues with `let` variables can be avoided by declaring them at the top of the scope in which they are used (doing so may impact readibility).